# How to update a prepopulated Android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I already created an application that implements a prepopulated database from the assets folder. On updating the app I want it to compare the existing database with another prepopulated database in the assets folder in order to add only new records to the database but keep the old ones. Do I have to copy the new database from assets to the device and use an sql execution to compare the two databases or is there a more efficient way.

Comment: Use `Version` in your database. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Comment: Is the reason to keep the old ones is because the user may have changed them? Otherwise, if the old database needs to be completely replaced, why not just completely replace it?

Comment: I need to keep the old values and only want to add new values to the tabel. The application asks the user different questions and compares the answers with the values in the database. It stores the amount of right answers to every question to ask the user questions given a wrong answer more often. To increase the number of questions, the database needs to be updated in consideration of keeping the number of correct answers.